Is it safe to UnregisterClass() inside the message loop?
I am making a little self-contained Dialog class. I can't find any documentation on UnregisterClass() regarding when it's safe to call this function.
According to the documentation:

Before calling this function, an application must destroy all windows created with the specified class.

Okay, so is it safe to call this function from inside the message loop?
LRESULT CALLBACK CustomDialog::DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND OkButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"Okay", WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 60, 26, hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(ButtonId), Instance, nullptr);
            SetWindowFont(OkButton);
            break;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) != ButtonId)
                break;
        }
        [[fallthrough]];
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EnableWindow(OwnerWindow, true);
            SetFocus(OwnerWindow);
            DestroyWindow(DialogWindow);
            break;
        }
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
        {
            UnregisterClass(DialogClassAtom);          //   <----- is it safe to do this?
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            break;                                     // Don't propagate WM_DESTROY to the main window
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
        default: { return CallWindowProc(reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(GetWindowLongPtr(OwnerWindow, GWLP_WNDPROC)), hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); }
    }
    return 0;
}

Technically, I've destroyed the window as per the documentation, and WM_NCDESTROY is sent after all the child windows are destroyed.  It just seems a little risky to be destroying a class whilst in the message loop.  There are probably other messages that might arrive after WM_NCDESTROY which may have a problem if the class is unregistered.
Ideally, you would unregister the window class after you'd left the message loop, like this:
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
UnregisterClass(DialogClassAtom);

Then you'd know everything would be safe, but since this is a general-use dialog class, callable from within the WNDPROC of an application window, I simply can't put cleanup code after a message handler which is actually for another window.
Any ideas?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654139/how-to-call-and-use-unregisterclass#comment47450349_29654139?

Good spot...  I did look for an answer before posting my question...]

it is safe call it on WM_NCDESTROY but you simply got ERROR_CLASS_HAS_WINDOWS.  There are probably other messages that might arrive after WM_NCDESTROY which may have a problem if the class is unregistered. - no other messages after WM_NCDESTROY, but windows procedure called reqursive.. say WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN -> WM_SYSCOMMAND -> WM_CLOSE -> WM_DESTROY. and you need call UnregisterClass after all this messages complete processing. for this need have counter member variable in CustomDialog for detect last message completed and here unregister class

When the message procedure receives WM_NCDESTROY, the message is simply telling you that the non-client area of the window is about to be destroyed. The window itself still exists. And as the UnregisterClass() documentation says: "If the class could not be found or if a window still exists that was created with the class, the return value is zero... Before calling this function, an application must destroy all windows created with the specified class."  So, calling UnregisterClass() inside of WM_NCDESTROY is "safe" only in that it won't crash, but it will not work.
